# do not redirect for certain file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following htaccess file. I do not want to perform a redirect from https to http on a certain file. how can i achieve this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.spectrumasa.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.spectrumgeo.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^intranet.spectrumasa.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.spectrumgeo.com/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.asb.com.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.spectrumgeo.com/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.spectrum-geopex\.com\.eg$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.spectrumgeo.com/spectrum-geopex [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I would like to access only the following through https `http://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w\.jpg$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something complex in picking with to redirect to `https://` from `http://` but you can accomplish a simple `redirect` on a single file via this method.

```
RewriteEngine

Redirect http://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg https://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg
```

This will solve accessing only the above url you have through `https://`